# Can Outlook send multiple simultaneous emails to different people without doing a bcc?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm looking to simultaneously send the same email to multiple recipients.  Let's say I want to email John and Bill the same email, I want them to be in the "To:" field, but I don't want them to see each other in the address list.  I don't want to bcc them both because then they see they are bcc'd.  I want them to each get their own copy of the identical email and to have 2 emails in my sent folder - one for each of them.

Essentially I want the same result as if I separately sent them each the identical email, but I'd like to do it in fewer steps.

Can I accomplish this either natively or with a plug-in, or some pre-existing code?

**NOTE:** I am looking to do this interactively (in real time), not in batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a tool called ReliefJet Essentials which does this.  The feature is called Send Messages Personally and can be found at http://www.reliefjet.com/Product/Features#Folders.  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do this is with Word Mail Merge. When you use the mail merge wizard, the first thing you will select is the document type. One of your choices is Email Message. Later, you will get to select Outlook as your source for the email addresses. Even nicer is the fact that you can include values from your contacts in your email text by including fields.

Each email is sent separately with its own To: address.

Comment: Thanks Sherry.  I was hoping for something more adhoc/real time, e.g. to do this with emails here and there without the planned setup process of mail merge.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking into this and isn't wanting the more advanced mail merge option:

Complete the first email without adding the 'To' address, click in the 'To' box and hit Ctrl+F. That should bring up an exact copy of the draft you just created. That saves you from having to copy and paste the subject, body, and attachments.