# Sending a mass mailing from a distribution group or contact list without listing all addresses

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Outlook send multiple simultaneous emails to different people without doing a bcc?](https://superuser.com/questions/180338/can-outlook-send-multiple-simultaneous-emails-to-different-people-without-doing)
>   [How to send group mail to multiple recipients, but have each recipient see their own name?](https://superuser.com/questions/224502/how-to-send-group-mail-to-multiple-recipients-but-have-each-recipient-see-their)

I'm looking to send out a customer survey to about 50 people in Outlook.  I have all my survey contacts grouped into a distribution list and a Contact folder.  I'd like to send this e-mail out once in a mass mailing, but I am required to have each individual recipient on each individual e-mail in the To field and no recipient is to see any other e-mail address.  Is this possible with Outlook 2007 or am I going to have to look for mass mailing software?

Thanks

edited to change "From field" to "To field" above.

**Solution 11/4/2011:**  I ended up using word to type up my survey, and then the Step by Step mail merge wizard to import my contacts and send off the survey.  I was not only able to enter a personal salutation, but also insure that each individuals email address showed up alone in the To: field.  I still had to log into Exchange as my boss to get her email address in the From: field, but no big deal.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to send group mail to multiple recipients, but have each recipient see their own name?](http://superuser.com/questions/224502/how-to-send-group-mail-to-multiple-recipients-but-have-each-recipient-see-their) also see [Can Outlook send multiple simultaneous emails to different people without doing a bcc?](http://superuser.com/questions/180338/can-outlook-send-multiple-simultaneous-emails-to-different-people-without-doing)

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook click the "CC" or "To" button then add the Group as a BCC, the BCC option will appear after clicking one of those buttons:

[image]

This will not allow recipients to see who else this email was sent to.

[Detailed Instructions.](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/How_to_Add_Bcc_Recipients_in_Outlook.htm)

Comment: Will this put each individual address into the To field of each individual e-mail sent as well?

Comment: no it will put it into the BCC field, if you put a name in the To field everyone will be able to see that address. This is how all of my vendors update me and how we update our customers at my company. Pretty standard practice...

Comment: Putting recipients to BCC while having something different in TO influences its SPAM confidence level.

Answer (score 1):

Using BCC will not put each individual into the TO field, it will put each individual into the BCC field individually from what they can see. And you need at least one address in the TO field in order to send a mass BCC message. When I send mass messages to an entire office I use BCC for everybody else and my own address in the TO field.

In order to send a mass mailing where each person sees only their own address in the TO field you need to use a mass email program, because each email would have to be sent individually.